# Are there disadvantages to making all columns except the primary key column in a table a unique index?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I want to avoid making duplicate records, but there are some occasions when updating the record, the values I receive are exactly the same as the record's version. This results in 0 affected rows which is a value I retain to help me determine if I need to insert a new transaction.

I've tried using a select statement to look for the exact transaction, but some fields (out of many) can be null which doesn't bode well when I have string variables that all have `'field1 = %s'` in their where clauses when I'd need something like `'field1 is NULL'` instead to get an accurate result back.

My last thought is using a unique index on all of the columns except the one for the table's primary key, but I'm not too familiar with using unique indexes. Should I be able to update these records after the fact? Are there risks to consider when implementing this solution?

Or is there another way I can tell whether I have an unchanged transaction or a new one when provided with values to update with?

The language I'm using is Python with mysql.connector

Comment: Depending on the size of your data, that could make for some very large indexes. Other than that, the right approach is very case-specific.

Comment: MySQL does have a null-safe comparison **`<=>`** operator.  This: `t.field1 <=> %s`  is equivalent to: `(t.field1 = '%s  OR ( t.field1 IS NULL AND %s IS NULL))`

Comment: This transaction table is is about 26 columns; as an afterthought I tried to make this unique index and mysql came back saying I'm only allowed 16 parts to my unique index haha.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks for letting me know about this! I'll try it out right away.